# How can I update the props.data from a child component?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am trying to display a range from an array that is being passed into a child.
My current Parent component is as follows:

```
import data from './data.json'
return ( 
    <Cell symbol={data.symbol} number={data.number} />
)
```

And that data is being passed into my Child component:

```
const [updatedSymbols, setUpdatedSymbols] = useState()

useEffect(() => 
    if(props.number === 1 || props.number === 2 || props.number === 3 ){
             setUpdatedSymbols(props.number)
            console.log("updated: " + props.number)
        }
    }, [props.symbol])

return (
    <div class="cell">
        {updatedSymbols}
    </div>
)
```

**QUESTION:** If you look at the useEffect, you will notice that within the if-statement, I am selecting the numbers I want and simply passing them into the useState, "setUpdatedSymbols".
My problem is that there are too many numbers that I need to select, about 100, how can I push them all into updatedSymbols without using || ?

Comment: Do you only need one item at a time? It is also unclear where `updatedData` comes from.

Comment: I edited my question a bit to show exactly where the data comes from and its flow. I hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whatever the numbers list you want to check before  you insert into your state you can collectively do this

```
    const [updatedSymbols, setUpdatedSymbols] = useState()
    const range = (from, to ) => {
       var collection = [];
       for(let i = from; i<=to ; i++) {
         collection.push(i);
       }
    return collection;
   }
    useEffect(() => 
        if(range(1,100).includes(props.number) ){
                 setUpdatedSymbols(props.number)
                console.log("updated: " + props.number)
            }
        }, [props.symbol])
    
    return (
        <div class="cell">
            {updatedSymbols}
        </div>
    )

    // this is magical trick
    // [1,2,3,4,5].includes(props.number); //if props.number happens to be in the array then it i'll give true
```

Comment: tel me about it mate, @habs

Comment: Hello mate, this almost works, although I still have to type [1,2,3......] up to 100. How can I simplify it to something like [1-100]?

Comment: nice le me edit my post

Comment: check if the above codes work and let me know :)

Comment: It works, thank you mate. Hakuna matata!

Comment: poa poa, from tanzania serengeti where king lion was taken :)